# possible to open Azure blobs in Skydrive?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, onedrive

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that runs on Azure.  I want to store a spreadsheet in the blob storage of Azure and allow the users to click on a link on my MVC application that opens up the spreadsheet in Skydrive, allowing them to edit it.  Any edits they make should be saved to the blob storage, or to Skydrive.  Is this possible at all?  I can think of some ways this could be theoretically achieved, but I don't know if any of these are actually available via. API:

- Directly opening a blob that references an XLS files in Azure, in Skydrive
- Skipping the Blob storage, and having a Skydrive account that "belongs" to the website.  Server side, it logs in to the account and it will open the XLS in its Skydrive.
- Skipping the Blob storage and requiring the user to login to a Live account, and then providing them access to the XLS file that is shared.

Are any of these possible?  I just want to make it easy to access and edit Word and Excel files in particular from my website.